# Elasticsearch indexing stops in middle

Tags: python, elasticsearch, runtime-error

When i am indexing my data it stops in middle, i have attached screenshot. one thing i have noticed is when ES is not indexing, python start to use swap memory upto 50 GB, and every-time my indexing stops at 54%. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

`

```
for ok, action in parallel_bulk(
        client=client,
        index=product_index_name,
        actions=actions,
        thread_count=4,
        request_timeout=100,
        chunk_size=100,
        raise_on_error=True,
        raise_on_exception=True
):
```

[image]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have used parallel bulk, to increase indexing speed. Also i had very very huge data set, which i reduced. That helped a lot

https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/7.x/helpers.html#elasticsearch.helpers.parallel_bulk